# Total stock of all variations from a variable product In Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I've tried to use [Get the total stock of all variations from a variable product In Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857156/get-the-total-stock-of-all-variations-from-a-variable-product-in-woocommerce/52861024#52861024), trying to make working this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_variable_product_stock_quantity', 20 );
function display_variable_product_stock_quantity(){
    wc_get_variable_product_stock_quantity( 'echo_html' );
}
```

with this one:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_variable_product_stock_quantity', 15 );
function display_variable_product_stock_quantity(){
    wc_get_variable_product_stock_quantity( 'echo_html' );
}
```

Or is it possible to get the total stock in the default element of quantities? for example. The stocks will be displayed in the highlighted below:

[image]

Comment: Not understandable: *"but I cant make the 2nd code work with the 3rd code. Is it possible to get the total stock in the default element of quantities?"*… You should clarify and reword.

Comment: sorry for confusing question. i've edited it regarded with thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following, changing of hook this way *(for archive pages as shop)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'display_variable_product_stock_quantity', 20 );
function display_variable_product_stock_quantity(){
    wc_get_variable_product_stock_quantity( 'echo_html' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work as asked.

Comment: The code worked but the stock quantity is still displayed at the bottom. how can I display only 1 stock info? is it possible to automatically set the total stocks quantity of the variable product as sum of its variants when i left the stocks unset? thanks sir :)

Comment: please help sir