# Display sum of variation in stocks of variable product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce, is it possible to display the sum of total stock of variations in variable product? I've the code from here [Get the total stock of all variations from a variable product In Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857156/get-the-total-stock-of-all-variations-from-a-variable-product-in-woocommerce)
 and its working but it displays two stocks infos. for example, I leave the stock in variable product as blank (because I wanted it to be auto generated as the sum of variation.) The default stock display say its out of stock, while the other one which is in the code displays the accurate one(one that highlighted in the picture). please help 
 [image]

I've used this code in the red text stocks.

```
function show_stock() {global $product;if ( $product->stock ) { // if manage stock is enabled if ( ! $product->managing_stock() && ! $product->is_in_stock() )        echo '';}if ( number_format($product->stock,0,'','') > 0 ) { // if stock is lowecho '<div class="remainingpc" style="text-align:center;"><font color="red"> ' . number_format($product->stock,0,'','') . ' Pcs Left</font></div>';} else {echo '<div class="remaining" style="text-align:center;"><font color="red">Out of Stock</font></div>'; }}  add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','show_stock', 10);
```

Comment: Hi Erwin! Could you post the code that was used to generate all of the html? Thanks!

Comment: sorry im just a newbie. here is the link https://digitsorani.net/?post_type=product&s=vivo+v11&asp_active=1&p_asid=2&p_asp_data=Y3VycmVudF9wYWdlX2lkPTIyOSZ3b29fY3VycmVuY3k9UEhQJnF0cmFuc2xhdGVfbGFuZz0wJmFzcF9nZW4lNUIlNUQ9dGl0bGUmY3VzdG9tc2V0JTVCJTVEPXByb2R1Y3Q=

Comment: I've edited the thread. I used that code in showing the red texted stocks

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the provided code with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'display_variable_product_stock_quantity', 10 );
function display_variable_product_stock_quantity(){
    wc_get_variable_product_stock_quantity( 'echo_html' );
}
```

Comment: This exact code has already been used and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53080715/3730754) for the same OP and it's apparently not solving his problem. That's why he asked this new question.

Comment: sorry sir, i am just a beginner thanks for response. how can i show all the stocks of all type of products?