# Display the stock availability for all product types in Woocommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I am using this code in showing the stocks of products:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'display_variable_product_stock_quantity', 10 );
function display_variable_product_stock_quantity(){
    wc_get_variable_product_stock_quantity( 'echo_html' );
} 

function show_stock() {
global $product;
if ( $product->stock ) { // if manage stock is enabled 
if ( ! $product->managing_stock() && ! $product->is_in_stock() )
        echo '';
}
if ( number_format($product->stock,0,'','') > 0 ) { // if stock is low
echo '<div class="remainingpc" style="text-align:center;"><font color="red"> ' . number_format($product->stock,0,'','') . ' Pcs Left</font></div>';
} 
else {
echo '<div class="remaining" style="text-align:center;"><font color="red">Out of Stock</font></div>'; 
}
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','show_stock', 10);
```

And if the product is a variable I use this answer code to display the stock availability:
[Get the total stock of all variations from a variable product In Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857156/get-the-total-stock-of-all-variations-from-a-variable-product-in-woocommerce/52861024#52861024)

How can I merge this codes in a single conditional function?

For example. if the products is a simple product, the other code for variable product will not display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will handle the display of the stock availability for all product types in woocommerce archive product pages as shop.

To handle the stock availability display for other product types than variable, you can use the dedicated function `wc_get_stock_html()` instead, which will simplify the code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wc_loop_get_product_stock_availability_text', 10 );
function wc_loop_get_product_stock_availability_text() {
    global $wpdb, $product;

    // For variable products
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {

        // Get the stock quantity sum of all product variations (children)
        $stock_quantity = $wpdb->get_var("
            SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
            JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
            WHERE p.post_type = 'product_variation'
            AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_parent = '".get_the_id()."'
            AND pm.meta_key = '_stock' AND pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL
        ");

        if ( $stock_quantity > 0 ) {
            echo '<p class="stock in-stock">'. sprintf( __("%s in stock", "woocommerce"), $stock_quantity ).'</p>';
        } else {
            if ( is_numeric($stock_quantity) )
                echo '<p class="stock out-of-stock">' . __("Out of stock", "woocommerce") . '</p>';
            else
                return;
        }
    }
    // Other products types
    else {
        echo wc_get_stock_html( $product );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: By the way sir, I am using ajax search plugin for woocommerce. i've used the {_stock} field in order to add the stocks in the results but {_stocks} displays not the total of variants. how can I know the field of the sum of stocks? thanks sir