# Sorting in variable products by availability

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im using this code in displaying the sum of the product variable stock quantities from a parent variable products based on: 
[Display the stock availability for all product types in Woocommerce archive pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235951/display-the-stock-availability-for-all-product-types-in-woocommerce-archive-page/53238468#53238468).

How can I make the sorting options to look at in the above script rather than the `_stock` meta?  here is the script that i am using to sort the products.

```
protected function get_settings_options() {

    $options = array(
        'by_stock'      => __( 'Available Stock', 'woocommerce-extra-product-sorting-options' ),
    );

    if ( ! self::is_wc_gte( '3.0' ) ) {
        $options['featured_first'] = __( 'Featured First', 'woocommerce-extra-product-sorting-options' );
    }

    return $options;
}
foreach( $new_sorting_options as $option ) {

        switch ( $option ) {

            case 'by_stock':
                $sortby['by_stock']       = __( 'Sort by availability', 'woocommerce-extra-product-sorting-options' );
            break;
        }
    }

    return $sortby;
}


public function add_new_shop_ordering_args( $sort_args ) {

    // If we have the orderby via URL, let's pass it in.
    // This means we're on a shop / archive, so if we don't have it, use the default.
    if ( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ) {
        $orderby_value = wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] );
    } else {
        $orderby_value = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    }

    // Since a shortcode can be used on a non-WC page, we won't have $_GET['orderby'] --
    // grab it from the passed in sorting args instead for non-WC pages.
    // Don't use this on WC archives so we don't break the default option
    if ( ! is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) && ! is_shop() && isset( $sort_args['orderby'] ) ) {
        $orderby_value = $sort_args['orderby'];
    }

    $fallback       = apply_filters( 'wc_extra_sorting_options_fallback', 'title', $orderby_value );
    $fallback_order = apply_filters( 'wc_extra_sorting_options_fallback_order', 'ASC', $orderby_value );

    switch( $orderby_value ) {



        case 'by_stock':

            $sort_args['orderby']  = array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', $fallback => $fallback_order );
            $sort_args['meta_key'] = '_stock';

        break;

    }

    return $sort_args;
}
```

Comment: We really don't catch what you are asking. For example: *"sorting options to look at in these script rather than the _stock meta"* is not understandable. Try to clarify your question, make it understandable, as you are asking that many times in different ways, without getting anything.

Comment: sorry for that sir but you always get what I wanted and it works fine. I just wanted to add some customization in it but I dont know how to apply it. I appreciate it thanks

Comment: Sorry but your new code is really extra long and nobody will go through it… You need to better explain with words what you are trying to get, adding in your question the shortest useful code for it.

Comment: thanks for the tip sir. I've already edited the code. how can I change the sorting options instead of  filtering from _stocks meta value, the filter will sort the result of code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235951/display-the-stock-availability-for-all-product-types-in-woocommerce-archive-page/53238468#53238468