# Ajax search plugin advance fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is there anyone who is familiar with the ajax search plugin in woocommerce?
How can I use the function from [Display the stock availability for all product types in Woocommerce archive pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235951/display-the-stock-availability-for-all-product-types-in-woocommerce-archive-page/53238468#53238468) to display the stocks in the fields instead of using this shortcode{_stocks}? I am not familiar with the terms sorry.