# Change the display of woocommerce stock values

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock

I would like to limit the display of stocks on my product pages (only on the frontend) in order to limit the stocks that are too high.

My question is similar to this article: [Set a max displayed available stock quantity on Woocommerce archives for variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64110064/set-a-max-displayed-available-stock-quantity-on-woocommerce-archives-for-variabl)

In it, the code below displays something similar but has several drawbacks:

- It displays the new stock on the product catalog pages and not directly replacing the stock on the product page
- It only works for variable products and not for simple products

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wc_loop_get_product_stock_availability_text', 10 );
function wc_loop_get_product_stock_availability_text() {
    global $wpdb, $product;

    $max_stock_qty = 50; // Maximum Number of Available Stock qty

    // For variable products
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {

        // Get the stock quantity sum of all product variations (children)
        $stock_quantity = $wpdb->get_var("
            SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
            JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
            WHERE p.post_type = 'product_variation'
            AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_parent = '".get_the_id()."'
            AND pm.meta_key = '_stock' AND pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL
        ");

        if ( $stock_quantity > 0 ) {
            // Here we limit the sock quantity display to 50 when it's up to 50
            $stock_quantity = $stock_quantity >= $max_stock_qty ? $max_stock_qty : $stock_quantity;
            
            echo '<p class="stock in-stock">'. sprintf( __("%s in stock", "woocommerce"), $stock_quantity ).'</p>';
        } else {
            if ( is_numeric($stock_quantity) )
                echo '<p class="stock out-of-stock">' . __("Out of stock", "woocommerce") . '</p>';
            else
                return;
        }
    }
    // Other products types
    else {
        echo wc_get_stock_html( $product );
    }
}
```

[image]

The returned value should replace the stock displayed on the product pages taking into account these conditions:

- When a stock is greater than 50, display a random number between 50 and 100.
- If the stock is less than 50, display the real value of the stock.

I am stuck and I don't know if I am going in the right direction,
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the `woocommerce_get_availability_text` and check the stock quantity.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_availability_text', 10, 2 );
function custom_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability = __( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce' );
    } elseif ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {
        $availability = $product->backorders_require_notification() ? __( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) : '';
    } elseif ( ! $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {
        $availability = __( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' );
    } elseif ( $product->managing_stock() ) {
        $stock_amount = $product->get_stock_quantity();
        // Check if Stock is less than 50.
        if ( 50 > $stock_amount ) {
            $availability = wc_format_stock_for_display( $product );
        } else {
            if ( false === ( $custom_availability = get_transient( 'custom_availability_text_' . $product->get_id() ) ) ) {
                $random       = wp_rand( 50, 100 );
                $availability = sprintf( __( '%s in stock', 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_stock_quantity_for_display( $random, $product ) );
                // Store for 6 hours. YMMV.
                set_transient( 'custom_availability_text_' . $product->get_id(), $availability, 6 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
            } else {
                return $custom_availability;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $availability = '';
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

I've updated the answer to include a 6 hour cache.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know if there is an easy way to not refresh the number every time the page loads?

Comment: Set a transient

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. Do you have an example I can add to the above code?

Comment: there must be an error, now all products show a stock equal to 1

Comment: @LorisGFT does this work for you now? Please accept answer if it does, so that it may help others.

Comment: Thank you it works, however the random number retained is the same for each product where the stock is >50. Is it possible to generate a new one for each product? With the same transient system

Comment: Check now. I reversed the order of the transient name.

Comment: It's all good! Thank you so much for your help, you are a generous person and it is a pleasure.